# Join two datasets with closest timestamp

Tags: sas

I need to join two tables with the closet timestamp.

```
data a;
  input id name $5. timea time8.;
  format timea time5.;
  cards;
  1 John 9:17 
  1 John 10:25
  2 Chris 9:17 
  3 Emily 14:25
;run;

data b;
  input id name $5. timea time8.;
  format timeb time5.;
  cards;
  1 John 9:00 
  1 John 10:00
  2 Chris 9:00 
  3 Emily 14:30
;run;

Table Want: 
id name timea timeb 
1  John  9:17 9:30
1  John  10:25 10:00
2  Chris 9:17 9:00
3  Emily 14:25 14:30
```

The way I did was to build a key= id||name in table b, sort by key and then create an interval in table b for each of timestamp. After the following code, I was not able to see the first time for John.

```
data time(rename=prev_TimeB = TimeB);
  length start_time end_time 8;
  retain start_time 0 prev_TimeB;
  set B(keep=TimeB) end = last;
  by key;
  if not first.key then do;
    end_time = TimeB - ((TimeB - prev_TimeB) / 2);
    output;
    prev_timeB = TimeB;
    if last.key then do;
    end_time = '23:59:59.999't;
    output;
  end;
  format prev_timeB start_time end_time time12.3;
  drop TimeB;
run;
```

Appreciate for your time!

Comment: Minimum absolute difference in time?  What do you want to do in case of ties?  Keep multiple records or use some type of tiebreaker?  What about records in A not in B at all?  What about those in B but not in A at all?

Comment: @Tom if records A is not in B at all, the just join for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Find the record where the difference is minimum absolute difference.  Easier to code in SAS since it will automatically re-merge aggregate function values with the detail records.

```
data a;
  input id name :$5. timea :time8.;
  format timea time5.;
cards;
1 John 9:17
1 John 10:25
2 Chris 9:17
3 Emily 14:25
4 Joe 11:21
;

data b;
  input id name :$5. timeb time8.;
  format timeb time5.;
cards;
1 John 9:00
1 John 10:00
2 Chris 9:00
3 Emily 14:30
;

proc sql ;
  create table C as
   select a.*
        , timeb
        , timea-timeb as seconds
        , abs(calculated seconds) as distance
   from a
   left join b
   on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
   group by a.id,a.name,a.timea
   having min(calculated distance) = calculated distance
  ;
quit;
```

Results

```
id    name     timea    timeb    seconds    distance
1    John      9:17     9:00      1020       1020
1    John     10:25    10:00      1500       1500
2    Chris     9:17     9:00      1020       1020
3    Emily    14:25    14:30      -300        300
4    Joe      11:21        .         .          .
```

Comment: I have large datasets in table a and table b. If I apply the method, I am afraid it will take too much resource and take forever. Thanks.

Comment: How large?  It should only be a problem if the average number of times per id is large.

Comment: Millions of obs in each table. But you are right. If the average number of times per id is not so large, it won't take too long.

Answer (score -1):

If you have sorted data sets A and B you may add temp variable pos=*n* to both tables:

```
Data a;
  set a;
  pos=_n_;
run;
Data b;
  set b;
  pos=_n_;
run;
```

You will have the following tables:
id name timea  pos     id name timea  pos 
1  John  9:17  1       1  John  9:00  1
1  John  10:25 2       1  John  10:00  1
2  Chris 9:17  3       2  Chris 9:00  3
3  Emily 14:25 4       3  Emily 14:30 4

And then you may use join in proc sql statement

```
proc sql;
  create table result as
  select *
  from a t1
  left join b t2
    on t1.pos=t2.pos;
quit;
```

If data sets not sorted - sort them firstly in right order

Comment: This doesn't work if you switch the order of two rows in one of the input datasets - you're not joining on nearest times, you're joining on position.

Comment: Thanks. But the actual obs in table a and b is not n-to-n match. It can be n to 1 match. Ideally, the way is to join a and b by finding the closest time and key. I don't know why the code above will overwrite the first.key